# Android - How can diplay pictures in a simpleApapter list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, picasso, simpleadapter

I'm trying to display te pictures in a SimpleAdapter listview. I included Picasso in my project but i don't know how to use Picasso with a SimpleAdapter.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> featured = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("productname", names[i]);
                hm.put("productprice", prices[i]);
                hm.put("productimage", images[i]);
                featured.add(hm);
            }

            String[] from = {"productname", "productprice", "productimage"};
            int[] to = {R.id.tv_ProductName, R.id.tv_ProductPrice, R.id.icon};

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, featured, R.layout.listitem_featured, from, to);
            HorizontalListView featuredList = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Featured);
            featuredList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The productname and price are displayed correctly. The product image isn't displayed at all. The images are urls, for example:

http://thingd-media-ec1.thefancy.com/default/171510088920465761_1686d73fc160.jpeg

What has to be done to display the images correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't "pass Picasso" to the adapter. You have to create your own custom adapter, it's not as daunting as it sounds. It may even be based on the `SimpleAdapter`. Like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

  public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int     resource, String[] from, int[] to){
  super(context, data, resource, from, to);
  }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
  View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

   // Then we get reference for Picasso
  ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
  if(img == null){
     img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageOrders);
     v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
  }
  // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
  String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_IMAGE);
  // do Picasso
  // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start

    Picasso.with(context).load(url)
            .resize(imageWidth, imageWidth).into(img);

  // return the view
  return v;
   }
}
```

**BTW** on Custom Adapter you can use it BY:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(yoururl)
            .resize(imageWidth, imageWidth).into(holder.imageItem);
```

**Then** you can just use this class without the image on the parameters (but it must still exist inside orderList).

```
ListView list= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
ListAdapter adapter = 
   new MyAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            orderList,
            R.layout.order_usa_row,
            new String[]{TAG_PRICE,TAG_TITLE,TAG_PSTATUS,TAG_PRICESYMBOL},
            new int[]{R.id.price,R.id.title,R.id.pstatus,R.id.symbol});
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For image size I think you need to re-size it !! as in example above  `.resize(imageWidth, imageWidth)` hope this help!!

Comment: How do i define and use the TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE and TAG_IMAGE? Maybe a stupid question...

Comment: NO... sure there is no question stupid BUT the unasked question is one !!  anyway mm it just example and the TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE and TAG_IMAGE refer to image location as ex, etc .. you can use them as your code need!

Comment: Ok i get it! but i have this array of url's which is retrieved from a php server by an AsyncTask. A string is declared like this: `private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";` How do i declare an array?

Comment: mm u need to change the MyAdapter parameters as your requirements which array of product-names, prices and images-paths!  as I tell you this Just ex as how you can use Picasso ...

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get it. Can you show me an example with my piece of code. I don't get how i get the array of urls `images[]` and use them in the MyAdapter class? I understand it need to retrieve the urls here `String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(.....);`

Comment: you do that already as you pass eg. to []  & from [] arrays to SImpleAdapter  in this line: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, featured, R.layout.listitem_featured, from, to); !!!

Comment: Ah ok! But what do i need to fill in here `String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(->HERE<-);`

Comment: your pass imagepthaes array which String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(imagepathes(position));

Comment: When i try this `String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE);` i get an error which says: Required: Java.lang.String Found Java.lang.Object