# NullPointerException when downloading images for ImageView in android

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to brush up on my android for a project at work, and it seams that im more out of touch than i first thought.

I am creating an app that uploads pictures to a remote server and then shows these uploads as thumbnails.

The section i am struggling is with downloading the image and applying it to the image view within a list view.

Im receiving a Null Pointer Exception which is never nice.

Im not sure if this is due to me starting a number of ASync tasks (one for each image) or if its something more obvious

Stack Trace

```
Process: com.example.alex.documentupload, PID: 5788
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.alex.documentupload.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImage.java:35)
        at com.example.alex.documentupload.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImage.java:14)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Android Code
Show images Class

```
package com.example.alex.documentupload;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.alex.documentupload.JSONParser;
import com.example.alex.documentupload.DownloadImageTask;

public class ShowImages extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView ver;
    TextView name;
    TextView api;
    ImageView img;

    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://www.500kgiveaway.co.uk/getimagesmob.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_PATH = "path";

    JSONArray android = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new JSONParse().execute();

        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // clear the list before adding more

                //update the list
                new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowImages.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL


               android = json;


                for(int i = 0 ; i < android.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String path = c.getString(TAG_PATH);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_PATH, path);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);



                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShowImages.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { TAG_PATH }, new int[] {
                            R.id.vers});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) list.findViewById(R.id.img))
                            .execute("http://www.500kgiveaway.co.uk/" + path);

//                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//                        @Override
//                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
//                                                int position, long id) {
//                            Toast.makeText(ShowImages.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//                        }
//                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void loadcamera(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowImages.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("dir", "BS"); //Optional parameters
        ShowImages.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    }

}
```

DownloadImages Class

```
package com.example.alex.documentupload;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 03/05/2015.
 */
 class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, this line `(ImageView) list.findViewById(R.id.img)` gives null, not finding the image view.

Comment: Any idea on a fix? When i check in debug this has a value, which would assume that it can find the object

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `DownloadImageTask` constructor just to be sure `bmImage` is `null`?

Comment: You are right . The bmimage is null in the download class. How can this be?

Comment: Chances are, you look for `R.id.img` in the wrong place. Are you sure your `list` as a `View` is a parent to a `View` with id `R.id.img`? I.e., `findViewById()` can only find a child of a view you're calling it on.

Comment: Did you tried to use Picasso or Glide for image loading?
http://square.github.io/picasso/
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: I am almost sure that list is the right view to be attaching this to, technically the view is being created dynamic, as the length of the json response varies so do the number of images on the page. The view must become accessable  within the call to ListAdapter adapter , a few lines above. And destroyed when its done

Comment: thanks @Stone, this seems a much better option. if i fail to resolve this, this is my next best option

Comment: Is there any way to call the image download within the adaptor call whilst the view is active?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? We have great libraries for this, I recommend Universal Image Loader or Picasso.

Comment: Hi ac . I only found out about such library's a few hours ago. However I do believe that the problem would still exist due to the issue I'm having referencing the view at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bit of a tricky fix, but got there in the end.

The issue was that i was unable to reference the imageview object inside the listview object whilst using a SimpleAdaptor.

The answer is that you need to create a custom class that extends SimpleAdaptor

I ended up using the picasso library, not because it helped fix the problem, more that it offered some image processing features, like resize etc which i had not previously allowed for.

I followed this answer [Android - How can diplay pictures in a simpleApapter list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064264/android-how-can-diplay-pictures-in-a-simpleapapter-list-view)

However i run in to additional issues with context.

Here is my custom class that extends SimpleAdaptor

```
package com.example.alex.documentupload;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExtendedAdaptor extends SimpleAdapter {

    public static Context NewContext;

    public ExtendedAdaptor(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int     resource, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        NewContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if(img == null){
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
        }
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get("path").toString();
        // do Picasso
        // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start



        Picasso.with(NewContext).load(url)
                .resize(100, 100).into(img);

        // return the view
        return v;
    }
}
```

and here is how i called it

```
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            ListAdapter adapter =
                    new ExtendedAdaptor(
                            context,
                            oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[]{TAG_PATH},
                            new int[]{R.id.vers});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Its all works pretty well, the image cache and image only download if they change.

I hope this helps someone else in the future

Thanks to all that contributed